# how to add characters to Chinese input method in emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I noticed that some Chinese characters are not accessible via the chinese-py and chinese-tonepy input methods. For example, the character *duì*: 䨺. I verified that in chinese-tonepy there are no submenus for *duì*. The character is, however, available and supported by emacs. How can I add additional characters to the pinyin menus?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add it by editing the files `PY.el` and `TONEPY.el`. You can find these files quickly using `M-x find-library`, assuming you have installed the Emacs Lisp source code along with Emacs.

In `PY.el`, I found this line:

```
("dui" "对队堆兑碓憝怼镦")
```

I added this character to the end of the string:

```
("dui" "对队堆兑碓憝怼镦䨺")
```

And then I typed `M-x eval-buffer`.

Likewise, in `TONEPY.el` I modified the line for `dui4` and came up with:

```
("dui4" "兑队对敦怼憝碓镦䨺")
```

After typing `M-x eval-buffer` in the corresponding buffer, the input methods `chinese-py` and `chinese-tonepy` let me type the character 䨺.

---

After changing these files, I wanted to save them.  That turned out to be more difficult.  At the bottom, they have this line:

```
;; coding: chinese-iso-8bit-unix
```

However, when saving with `C-x C-s`, Emacs complains that 䨺 cannot be encoded with this coding system.  Thus I modified that line to read:

```
;; coding: utf-8
```

And told Emacs to save the file as `utf-8`. It seemed to work, but I'm not sure if this breaks anything.

---

This is probably not the right way to go about this.  The comments at the top of `PY.el` and `TONEPY.el` state that they were generated from the files `pinyin.map` and `TONEPY.tit` respectively, so the right thing to do is presumably to update those data files, or add more entries to whatever database they are taken from.

Comment: Great that you found the file. This means that the elisp source files need not be modified: What can be done is to to find the specific pinyin, add what I want to it, and add this to a special tonepy-additions.el file, or even to the .elisp:

(quail-defrule "dui4" "兑队对敦怼憝碓镦䨺")

Thanks!